# Получить из списка слова, которые начинаются с буквы S используя lambda expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

есть список:

**dl = ['sixtysix', 'eight', 'twentyone', 'seven', 'forty', 'sixteen']**

используя lambda expression нужно получить результат:

**[sixtysix, seven, sixteen]**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотря что Вы имели в виду под *"используя lambda expression"*.
В `lambda` можно обернуть `listcomp` и это вполне будет удовлетворять условию.

***Пример:***

```py
def main():
    dl = ['sixtysix', 'eight', 'twentyone', 'seven', 'forty', 'sixteen']

    f = lambda li: [x for x in li if x.startswith('s')]

    result = f(dl)
    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```py
['sixtysix', 'seven', 'sixteen']
```

Comment: есть ли более короткий способ, если опустить условие "используя lambda" ?
спасибо большое за Ваш ответ!

Comment: @Maksym Более короткий способ — это просто использовать списковое включение. Конструкция `[x for x in dl if x.startswith('s')]` вернёт Вам то, что Вы хотите.

Answer (score 4):

Решение в функциональном стиле:

```
res = list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith("s"), dl))
```

результат:

```
In [5]: res
Out[5]: ['sixtysix', 'seven', 'sixteen']
```